# pull to a second remote repository: push only

Tags: git

I've my own Ubuntu server with my bare repositories. I push/pull to/from it from three locations:

- Two personal computers, using the ssh protocol.
- The same server on another location, using the file protocol

I'd like to have a copy on github of one of my projects, but I'll never pull from it, only push, to give public access to my project. So my desired workflow is:

- I do any changes on any of my local repositories.
- I push the changes to my own server.
- I pull when I'm on any of the other two machines.
- When I'm happy (with the current changes... because I'm always personally happy), I'd like to `cd` to my bare repository folder and push from there to the github server.

I prefer to push from the bare repository because I'd like to have a centralized site where I know will always be up-to-date, like if it were the official place to upgrade the github repo (with so many ssh connections, it's common to cause pitfalls from being on the wrong location, so I want to be fully aware of where I am).

How could I do that? Additionally, is there a way to configure, for a specific local repo (the bare, for instance), that pulling from a specific remote is forbidden? (I don't want to pull from the github repo even by mistake, because sometimes my workflow includes some scripting magic).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could get what you want by:

- Only configure the GitHub remote on the bare repository (this way it's not available anywhere else so you can't accidentally push to or pull from it).
- Configure separate push and pull urls.  Since you want to be able to push but not pull:

  ```
  git remote add github file:///dev/null
  git remote set-url --push github git@github.com:you/your_repo
  ```

  This configures a push-only remote: attempts to pull will result in an error.

Comment: Last question, using `git-remote` only modifies `.git/config` isn't? Just in case some day I want to remove the push-only restriction.